# Laravel & Blade templating

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-blade

I am new to laravel & blade templating also MVC.. I just want to know how to use ids on template file to fetch db values.. can anyone tell me? I can able to save values to db.. but how to get back on same template?

Answer (score 1):

If you're a visual learner, I recommend Laracasts. They've got lots of free content to get you up and running with laravel in no time. They have paid content too. I recommend you visit this link to get [the basics of laravel](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017)

Answer (score 0):

First read the full docs from the Laravel. After read this
[link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers) . The crud is the best for this.:))

Comment: thanks for ur reply.. actually I want to get values from user and save. and need to show on same page

Comment: Glad to help you. :) Close the topic :)